# Are there any specialized databases for event-sourcing?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am very interested in the event-sourcing pattern and I would like to know if there are any databases that can help to use this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any specialized databases for event-sourcing?

Yes.

[Event Store](https://www.eventstore.com/) is the "big iron" player in the space; a database built from the ground up specifically for storing streams of events.

You can also find projects that build out event stores on top of relational schemas, for example [message-db](https://github.com/message-db/message-db), which builds an event store on top of Postgres.